# how to remove my control from the actionsheet without click on actionsheet's buttons in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how to remove my control from the actionsheet without click on actionsheet's buttons in iphone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you want to dismiss the Action Sheet without tapping any buttons from Action Sheet.

am i right or not ?

You can do it by putting a CancelButton in ActionSheet.

```
- (void)showOpenOptions
{
UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
        initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Open link in external application?", @"Open in external application")
        delegate:self
        cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel")
        destructiveButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Open Link", @"Open Link")
        otherButtonTitles:nil];

[sheet showInView:self.view];
[sheet release];
}
```

i hope you got your answer.

even if any problem then leave a comment. and mark it as correct by clicking correct sign if you get resolved.

Comment: +1 but what if actionsheet having another view in it and that view has a button and by clicking on that button actionsheet must be dismiss ? any idea ? ..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking. If you mean "how can I remove a button from an action sheet once I've already shown it", you can do so by digging through its `subviews` array, but you probably shouldn't. If you mean something else, please clarify your question.